# The preposition "zu" with infinitives

Tags: grammar, difference

> Eine Woche im Ferienhaus zu gewinnen.

The sentence translates "Win a week in a Cottage", but my question is why there is a *zu*? Can the sentence stand alone without it?

Here's another sentence:

> Zu wissen, wie Gerichte entschieden haben, kann sich auch für Sie auszahlen.

Can one just say:

> Eine Woche im Feiernhaus gewinnen.

and

> Wissen, wie Gerichte entschieden haben, kann sich auch für Sie auszahlen.

Or will it change their meaning?

Comment: Nicht zu verwechseln mit "zugewinnen", obwohl der Unterschied so gering ist. Ich vermute fast einen historischen Zusammenhang. Jedenfalls sagt niemand "Verdienst zu zu gewinnen", allenfalls "hinzu zu gewinnen", aber zu-inf. wird in der Regel nicht mit allen Verben verwendet werden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is marketing language. Just like newspaper headlines, things are getting shortened and parts of sentences are being omitted as the editor sees fit, while still being grammatical.

> [Sie können] 1 Woche im Ferienhaus gewinnen.
>
> [Es gibt] 1 Woche im Ferienhaus zu gewinnen.
>
> [Gewinnen Sie] 1 Woche im Ferienhaus.

It depends on what is being omitted. It probably also depends on how much space there is for the statement in the final, published copy, so the editor may change their mind a few times before the thing goes to print or production.

On the other hand, the sample clause

> Zu wissen, wie [...]

would be preferable over

> Wissen, wie [...]

This becomes obvious when re-arranging the sentence.

> Es kann sich auch für Sie auszahlen, zu wissen, wie Gerichte entschieden haben.

There is no grammatical way to omit the "zu" in this case.